# ffmpeg filter / stuttering / how to smooth camera movement

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, camera

I'm using ffmpeg witht he following code for some camera movement effects.

```
 -filter:v "crop=in_w/1.2:in_h/1.2:(in_w-out_w)/2+((in_w-out_w)/2)*sin(t*0.1):(in_h-out_h)/2 +((in_h-out_h)/2)*sin(t*0.4)"
```

Its working but the camera movement is stuttering and looks realy ugly that way (also on 60 fps). I hope someone could lead me to a idea to have a more smooth movement.

Comment: Enclose the sin in trunc and check.

Comment: May you give me an example? I used `crop=in_w/1.2:in_h/1.2:(in_w-out_w)/2+((in_w-out_w)/2)*(sin(t*0.1)):(in_h-out_h)/2 +((in_h-out_h)/2)*(sin(t*0.4))` and there is no visual change